# How can I call IValueConverter by user request? [XamDataGrid record index]

Tags: wpf, binding, infragistics, ivalueconverter, xamdatagrid

I want to add record index like MS Excel in my XamDataGrid control. I use for this trick with IValueConverter. I define some template for displaying record indexes width this XAML-code:

```
<local:RowNumberConverter x:Key="rowNumberConverter" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:RecordSelector}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igDP:RecordSelector}">
                    <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource rowNumberConverter}">
                                    <Binding />
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

RowNumberConverter defined as:

```
class RowNumberConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
      #region IMultiValueConverter Members

      public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {

         //get the grid and the item
         Object item = values[0];
         XamDataGrid grid = values[1] as XamDataGrid;

         int index = grid.RecordManager.Unsorted.IndexOf(((DataRecord)item));

         return index.ToString();
      }

      public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      #endregion
   }
```

This works perfectly when I add records in my XamDataGrid instance, but when I sort data by any field in my datagrid, record indexes also sorts (value converter does not calling when I press sort button). Maybe I can call it manually?

Thanks for any advices and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution with help of Infragistics support. It's combines several methods. So...

**Write MultiValueConverter:**

public class RowNumberConverter : IMultiValueConverter {

```
   #region IMultiValueConverter Members

   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
       if (values != null && values[0] != null)
       {
           Record r = values[0] as Record;
           return (r.VisibleIndex + 1).ToString();
       }
       else
           return null;
   }

   public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
   #endregion
```

}

**Register DepencyProperty:**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DummyValueProperty =

      DependencyProperty.Register("DummyValue", typeof(int), typeof(XamRibbonWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));

        public int DummyValue
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(DummyValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DummyValueProperty, value); }
        }
```

**Write style:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:RecordSelector}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igDP:RecordSelector}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="#FFD4D4D4" BorderThickness="0,1.5,1.5,0" Background="#FFF1F1F1">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="{Binding Path=FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}}}">
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=rowNumberConverter}">
                                        <Binding />
                                        <Binding Path="DummyValue" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50"/>
    </Style>
```

**Add event handlers for sorting event, delete event etc. with this code:**

```
this.DummyValue++;
```

Thats all. Good luck :).

Answer (score 1):

Value conversion happens when the properties are accessed (get/set) via DataBinding. You're sorting is not triggering this and I don't suspect you want it to since your sort probably does not work on the original collection and you'd probably get the items with the wrong row index on them again. I don't know of anyway, other than explicitly triggering a binding refresh, of getting the ValueConverter implementation to work.

Check [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatesource.aspx) for information on explicitly calling the UpdateSource method. I don't know if this will solve your problem unless you sort on the original object collection with LINQ.

Comment: Doesn't work in that it doesn't update, or that it doesn't change the row index number in your grid?

Comment: I believe this is because the items are coming out of the source collection in the same order and then they are being sorted. So as they are getting converted, they are getting their row index and then they are being sorted by the grid.  You will need to sort on the source collection.

Comment: But sorting is xamDataGrid build in function. Thanks for your advices, but I can't mark it as answer, because maybe somebody know working solution for Infragistics xamDataGrid component. Thanks!